# Woocommerce returns Product post_status as published even tho it is in status draft

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

Heyho,

I've got a problem getting the post_status of a WP_PostObject which is a Woocommerce-Product.
I get all products doing this query:

```
$onlineShopProducts = get_posts([
            'post_type' => ['product', 'product_variation'],
            'orderby' => 'post_title',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'numberposts' => -1
        ]);
```

Now I want to filter out all products which are in status draft during a foreach-loop:

```
foreach ($onlineShopProducts as $onlineShopProduct){
            if($onlineShopProduct->post_status != 'publish'){
                continue;
            }
            doSomething($onlineShopProduct)
        }
```

but $onlineShopProduct->post_status and get_post_status($onlineShopProduct->ID) both return "publish", even tho they are set "Draft" in the product-edit-view... (it's in german)

[image]

is there some sort of post_meta I have to query or is this a know bug of some sort? How can I filter out the drafted products?

Greetings

Comment: You did not specify the post status you wanted when making the query, so no draft posts are fetched. Also note that `get_posts` by default will ignore caching and give a performance hit unless `suppress_filters` is set to false. `WP_Query` does not have this limitation

Comment: Hey Tom - Thanks for your input... But problem is, that I'm getting too much, not too little... I get posts which have the draft-status in the backend as published posts in the code.

Comment: If you only want published posts you should say so in the arguments

Comment: Okay... Now I don't know if you don't get it cause you don't know what I'm talking about or if you even read the question... So again... There appear posts which are on "draft" in the backend but have status "published" when I view them in code... Let's say I look at post with ID 123 -> In the backend it sais status: "draft" get_post_status(123) returns "published" and all those are woocommerce-products... You get it now?

Comment: I got it when I first read the question, and I'm saying, there's a really easy parameter you can pass to `get_posts` to tell it which post statuses you want, you don't need to call `get_post_status`. If you don't want `draft` posts, just say so to `get_posts`, the if check you're having problems with is unnecessary. Also keep in mind that WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugins are off topic, and be nice, your last comment was quite rude. Aside from a code of conduct, I'm not a support desk employee, my time is volunteered and unpaid, and there are no entitlements.

Comment: Tom... Seriously... Dude... THE RESULTSET FROM get_posts CONTAINS POSTS WHICH SHOULD NOT BE THERE SINCE THEY HAVE THE FREAKING WRONG STATUS IN THE CODE!!! BUT IN THE BACKEND-VIEW THEY HAVE THE CORRECT ONE! JESUS!
This is not about beeing a-hole but getting the same useless answer 3 times in a row now... I just want to know that behaviour (HAVING THE WRONG STATUS CODE-WISE) is a known bug or if there is anything woocommerce does which I haven't figured yet but which describes why the products are post-status "publish" while the backend sais "draft"... They are posts with type "product".

Comment: These are comments, not answers, and there is no need to be rude and hostile. Instead of assuming I don't understand, humor me and try what I suggested then report back the results. If it is indeed something WooCommerce does, then you need to ask in a WooCommerce support route, not here. 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here and not in this stacks scope. Any answers you get here will be general WP answers. My answer below tells you how to fetch posts without fetching the draft posts as requested in the Q, if it does not then please comment on it with the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, delete the `if` check you're having problems with, and add the `post_status` parameter to `get_posts`.

For example:

```php
$args = [
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => false,
];
$only_published_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Notice I added `suppress_filters` and set it to `false` so that it can be sped up.

Likewise we can pass an array of the statuses we do want, e.g.

```php
$args = [
    'post_status' => [ 'publish', 'pending' ],
    'suppress_filters' => false,
];
$only_published_and_pending_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Or everything except published posts:

```php
$args = [
    'post_status' => [ 'future', 'draft', 'pending' ],
    'suppress_filters' => false,
];
$not_published = get_posts( $args );
```

Or private posts:

```php
$args = [
    'post_status' => [ 'private' ],
    'suppress_filters' => false,
];
$private_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Or all post statuses, including revisions and auto drafts:

```php
$args = [
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'suppress_filters' => false,
];
$all_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

**There are a limited number of post statuses that come with core, and they're hard coded, so you can just list the ones you want, and omit the ones you don't.**

More information at: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#status-parameters

*Note that while this is the canonical standard WordPress method, plugins may employ custom post statuses, or ignore statuses altogether if they are poorly built. In these situations you will need to contact their dev support routes.*

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else comes here looking for this and doesn't get the answer, a Product's Variation can be set to Status Publish even when the Main Product is set to Draft. That's what was happening to me. So the product was set to draft, but the variation was set to Publish.

Comment: Hi, I ran into this too. Good catch! I'd like to improve this answer by adding instructions: to un-publish a variation uncheck the 'Enabled' checkbox within the settings for any variation.